# Add feature to POPUP the overflowed code

Tags: feature-request, design, editor, code

1) In many cases, we see the "scrolling-bar"-ed codes. It would be nice, it there was "full-screen view" button on the right bottom side, af, after clicking on it, the code should show/popup on full-screen, and thus we can easily look thought the whole codes...

[image]

2) to mention, I also wished in editor, we had the same on the right edge:

[image]

Comment: 3) Format code so it uses < 100 columns and therefore doesn't wrap.